# Should I have to add a lock to a socket while two or more threads want to access it?

Tags: sockets

I get a socket from the accept function in main process, and two or more threads can send data from it. Then, the access of the socket must be mutually-excluive when two or more threads want to send data from it parallelly. My problem is if the OS will add a lock to the connected socket in the bottom of the system .

Comment: I won't know the answer, but you should probably add what OS you're interested in, and what library you use (possibly even what language)

Comment: I'm sorry. The OS is freeBSD and the library is POSIX socket library(in C). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention `accept()`, I take it we are talking about stream sockets.

You can send simultaneously from multiple threads or processes on the same socket, but there is no guarantee that the data from multiple senders will not be interleaved together. So you probably don't want to do it.

If you are sending small amounts of data at a time that don't cause the socket to block, you can probably expect the data blocks submitted to each simultaneous `send()`/`write()` call to arrive contiguously at the other end. PROBABLY. You can't count on it.